# Change shipping class based on cart items shipping class count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I'm having trouble with the default WooCommerce shipping class settings. We have a small webshop with 2 shipping costs. One for products that fit in the mailbox, and other that don't.

We would like to make a setting that if there are 2 products with mailbox shipping class, than the price becomes a package price.

Now on default WooCommerce only charges 1x the mailbox shipping class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to make your shipping settings as in the below screen, for "Flat rate" shipping method and only one shipping class named "Mailbox" *(setting the desired amounts for "Mailbox" or No shipping class)*:

[image]

> So some of your products will have the "Mailbox" shipping class and all others no shipping class. The products without shipping class *(No shipping class)* will be your "package.

The following code will remove the cart items shipping class, if there is more than one item with the "Mailbox" shipping class:

```
// Updating cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_change_shipping_class', 30, 1 );
function change_change_shipping_class( $cart ) {
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class SLUG
    $mailbox_shipping_class = 'mailbox';

    $mailbox_count = 0;

    // 1st cart item Loop: Counting "mailbox" shipping classes cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Set the new price
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $mailbox_shipping_class ) {
            $mailbox_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    // If there is more than one item we continue
    if( $mailbox_count <= 1 )
        return; // Exit

    // 2nd cart item Loop: Reset the cart items with shipping class "mailbox"
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if(  $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $mailbox_shipping_class ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_shipping_class_id('0');
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Excellent code! How could I change the shipping class using the total price instead of the quantities, that is, if I have 150 dollars of the "mailbox" class that becomes the "0" class?@LoicTheAztec

Comment: @CarlosGomez try to replace `$cart_item['quantity'];` by `$cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];` and also ;`if( $mailbox_count <= 1 );` by ;`if( $mailbox_count < 150 );` where 150 is the threshold amount… it should work as you expect.

Comment: It,s perfect!! Thank you @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @LoicTheAztec you are TRUE WooCommerce GURU! Deserve a medal! thank you

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is this code still working after 8.0? Because I am now working for an hour to run this code, I have adjusted everything 1:1 and nothing changes for the shipping in the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code, worked great!

I used another shipping class id, not the 0. Got the id by inspecting the code of the page where you can enter the rates. (It said name="woocommerce_flat_rate_class_cost_58", so the id is 58.) That's my "big parcel" class. This way, it gets exported to my mail/label plugin properly.