# WooCommerce: Change shipping class based on quantity in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm having difficulty with the shipping classes in WooCommerce. It's a webshop containing products for mailbox and packages.

However, if the cart contains 3 or more "mailbox" products, then the shipping class should change to "package".

I've tried changing the code from this question: [Change shipping class based on cart items shipping class count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328206/change-shipping-class-based-on-cart-items-shipping-class-count-in-woocommerce?newreg=4c5bdcb20ea245768b1282368192b34f) , but I couldn't figure it out.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What did you change? What is the problem?

Comment: I tried to change this line `$cart_item['data']->set_shipping_class_id('0');` to a different ID, which didn't work. 

I tried to add a shipping class `$package_shipping_class = 'package';` and place it as `$cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() ==$package_shipping_class );` on the last line (so instead of  `$cart_item['data']->set_shipping_class_id('0');`

Then when I go to my cart and I add 3 products it just says the label "Shipping costs" with actually adding shipping costs.

Comment: I found a different solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be that you change the slug naming in the code.
Just implemented this and works fine!

```
// HERE define your shipping class SLUG
$mailbox_shipping_class = 'your-mailbox-shipping-class-slug';
```

Comment: Please avoid asking questions (even rhetoric ones) in answers, it risk being flagged as "not an answer".